# Using a public api to fetch data into my html page.need help in figuring out name of object to fetch

Tags: javascript, html, api

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MjTG.png)

Guys,i am using this public api to fetch its "city" field,api is returning me status("ok"/"fail") and an array named result which further has -lastname,country ,city etc within it.

I wish to pick data from "city" given in the array[0] from the array[0] and array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MjTG.png) which this api is fetching for me.
How to fetch city?
i used this-
[js code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph3yh.png)

heres my html tag where i wish to display the city i am getting from api
[html code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxAlr.png)

its my first time posting query,sorry for hotch potch

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
let city = data.result[0].city;
```